# reinstall angular universal after angular cli upgrade

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I upgraded my `angular cli` from the 6 version to the 8.1, `Angular universal` has changed the simple construction method by `@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader`, I should re-deploy, clear the old configuration.

1. run `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]`

Error message:

```
Skipping installation: Package already installed
Target name already exists.
```

2. run `npm install --save @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader`
3. build universal, run `build:ssr` ("npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server")

Error message:
[image]

I need to remove some files, modify some files and reinstall `@nguniversal/express-engine`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To reinstall the angular universal using ng add. You will need to remove all the files was generated by it. Such as

- src/main.server.ts
- src/app/app.server.module.ts
- src/tsconfig.server.json
- webpack.server.config.js
- server.ts

In angular.json, you will need to remove the "server" configuration. 
Something like :

```
 "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

After that, you can just do

> ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]

It should work.

Comment: I tried your method but still got errors: `Skipping installation: Package already installed
Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined`. My "server" item does not have "configurations".

Comment: not working
Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Comment: if you getting package already installed, npm uninstall it, then do ng add