# angular unversal, angular 6 to 9, Install new version of angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular9

After I tried to upgrade my angular version(6 to 9), I found that the old version of angular universal could be successfully packaged, but could not run normally.

Old angular universal packaging command：

```
 ng build --prod ; ng run [project name]:server ; npm run webpack:server
```

Some files will be created before this command works, but the steps are complicated and I have forgotten.

I try to solve problems in the process, but new problems keep appearing.

So I plan to try the [new version of angular universal](https://angular.cn/guide/universal), but it seems that the two versions of angular universal conflict with each other.

I had a problem running the first command:

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]`

Error message:

```
Skipping installation: Package already installed
ERROR! server.ts already exists.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.0-rc.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "csspin": "^1.1.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^5.1.2",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.3.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.12.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.54",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.5",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow This Link: [reinstall angular universal after angular cli upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517186/reinstall-angular-universal-after-angular-cli-upgrade/59387657#59387657)

Remove all of the following files

- src/main.server.ts
- src/app/app.server.module.ts
- src/tsconfig.server.json
- webpack.server.config.js
- server.ts

Remove the "server" configuration. Something like:

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/server",
    "main": "src/main.server.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After that, you can just do

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]
```